# How to add commas to thousands numbers coming from API using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

[Link to live code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/jpmo3?file=/js/app.js)

I'm currently pulling in API data for products that have price points in the thousands. Below, I've tried adding the code `toLocaleString()` to the price, which in full below is `<p id="price">$${product.price?.text.toLocaleString() ?? ""}</p>`. However it doesn't seem to add a comma to make the price read in the thousands (example - 1,000).

**JS Code**

```
// Fetch Data
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const data = await res.json();
  let output = "";
  // Loop through first 'groups' array
  data.groups.map(function (group) {
    // Loop through each 'equipments' array
    group.equipments.map((product) => {
      // Define below variable to match cat products only
      const catProducts =
        product["dealer-name"] === "DEALER NAME";
      // If the dealer name is everything but cat products (aka only bfe products)..
      if (!catProducts) {
        // Loop through each 'photos' array
        product.photos.map(() => {
          // Then output the data
          // If year is undefined, replace with empty string
          output += `
            <div class="card">
            <img class="img-fluid" src=${product.photos[0].text} alt=${
            product.model
          } />
            <div class="card--body">
              <h3>${product.year ?? ""} ${product.manufacturer} ${
            product.model ?? ""
          }</h3>
              <p>${product.city ?? "City Not Available"}, ${product.state}</p>
              <p>${product.hours} hours</p>
              <p id="price">$${product.price?.text.toLocaleString() ?? ""}</p> <--- Not working
              <a href='https://used.battlefieldequipment.ca/en/${
                product["group-code"]
              }/${
            product["serial-number"]
          }' class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
              </div>
            </div>         
        `;
        });
      }
    });
  });
  // Add to slider
  $(".used-slider").slick("slickAdd", output);
}

getData();
```

Any idea how I can get the API prices to show up with a comma, making them show properly as thousands numbers?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number has to be a number rather than a string for that to work. `parseFloat(numberAsString).toLocaleString()`